# Can we locate the I/O wait for an unintrruptable sleep process individually?

Tags: server, kernel, suspend, process

*top* command shows overall I/O wait status for the processes and "iostat" shows how much the processes are doing I/O requests. But i want to know that my particular process is in the uninterruptible sleep, so i want to investigate from how much time it is in that state.

Answer (score 1):

/proc/[pid]/stat may provide some of the data you are interested in. Field 3 contains the process state flag, if it is a "D" state it is waiting in an uninterruptible disk sleep state.  One could poll the proc file and figure out the proportion of time the process is in the D state.